# Double-, triple- click behaviour in HTML tables

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a table with two columns: Domain and Date.
Double-clicking on Date  allows to select all Date for copying it via CTRL+V, but double click on Domain  does not allow to select it fully and just the part before the dot. I can only select the full domain by triple-clicking, but when I copy it via CTRL+V and past to the text file it adds the tabulator field in the end. Why does it happen? How can I select the full domain by double click? Or how can I get rig of the tabulator field for triple-click?

I already tried to wrap domain into the `<p>`, `<span>` and `<div>`. It didn't help.

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Domain</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>domain.com</td>
<td>21.12.20</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```